# Why this function doesn't return a list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove tabs and end of lines from content pasted from a table and create a list with its elements:

```
string = 'a sdfs 234f f ff2e '

def pasteTrim(var):   
    var = str(var)     
    var = var.replace('\n',' ').replace('\t',' ')    
    var = var.split(' ')     
    return var

pasteTrim(string)

print(type(string))
```

The output is `<class 'str'>` while I expected `<class 'list'>` because of `var.split`.

[EDIT]

According to the answers: in this example, the assignments inside pasteTrim() don't extend beyond the function execution itself.

Is there any way to provide a variable as an argument to a function and have its value modified just by executing the function?

Comment: You are not returning anything in your function. You have to actually return what you want to return explicitly.

Comment: I tryed to `return` var and test its type afterwards, and it's still a string

Comment: Show that attempt as well. It's closer to what you should do.

Comment: @Fred Yes, because you aren't actually then assigning the return of `pasteTrim` to anything. `res = pasteTrim(string)`. The result won't be in `string`. Also, *strings* are immutable in Python anyway.

Comment: That's obviously because you have `type()` in front of string and you do not have a return statement

Comment: `print(type(string))` prints the type of the *input*…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'a sdfs 234f f ff2e '

def pasteTrim(var):   
    var = str(var)     
    var = var.replace('\n',' ').replace('\t',' ')    
    var = var.split(' ')     
    return var

string = pasteTrim(string)

print(string)
>>>['a', 'sdfs', '234f', 'f', 'ff2e', '']
```

You need to return something and then assign the value to variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
string = 'a sdfs 234f f ff2e '

def pasteTrim(var):   
    var = str(var)     
    var = var.replace('\n',' ').replace('\t',' ')    
    var = var.split(' ')
    return var

list_of_words = pasteTrim(string)

print (list_of_words)
```

You have to use return keyword to return the list you have prepared in var using split.
This list is then assigned to `list_of_words`. You can then print or do anything with it.